# M1でCannot install in Homebrew on ARM processorエラー

Tags: macos, homebrew, neovim

`brew install neovim`
を実行すると

```
 Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump
```

とエラーが出ました。
Homebrewのインストール推奨先が/local/bin配下でしたが、M1　MacOS ARMからはインストール推奨先がopt/homebrewへ変更になり、パスの変更が必要らしいです。

パスを変更する手順を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 参考: [Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64963370/2322778)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrewの初期設定を.zprofileファイルに追記してください。
ターミナルを再起動すれば、環境変数PATHが設定されます。

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Comment: そちらのコードを実行してみましたが同じようなエラーがでてしまいました

Comment: ＞on ARM processor in Intel default prefix
CPUアーキテクチャのエラーが出ています。
Homebrewの環境構築時から間違っているのでは？
M1なのにIntel版のhomebrewをインストールしてしまったとか。
Rosettaを有効にしているとか。